# Custom type definitions for LoDash internal functions not picked up by tsc

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm writing a variation of `_.cloneDeep` and starting with LoDash's implementation of `baseClone`. It imports several internal LoDash functions so I created type definitions for those. I can't get `tsc`/`vscode` to recognize those definitions though.

[image: Source Code]

Setup is:

**`src/types/lodash.d.ts`**

```js
declare module 'lodash/_arrayEach' {
  export default function _arrayEach<T>(
    array: T[],
    iteratee: ArrayIterator<T, boolean>,
  ): T[];
}

declare module 'lodash/_assignValue' {
  export default function _assignValue(
    target: unknown,
    key: string,
    value: unknown,
  ): void;
}

// .. and rest of referenced internal methods
```

**`src/clonePlus.ts`**

```js
/// <reference path="./types/lodash.d.ts" />

import Stack from 'lodash/_Stack';
import arrayEach from 'lodash/_arrayEach';
import assignValue from 'lodash/_assignValue';
import cloneBuffer from 'lodash/_cloneBuffer';
import copyArray from 'lodash/_copyArray';
```

**`tsconfig.json`**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

besides using `/// <reference` I've also tried putting the file `lodash.d.ts` in `node_modules/@types/myapp/index.d.ts` with the same result.

`tsc` produces the same error as `vscode` (newlines added for clarity):

```
src/clonePlus.ts:83:29 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file 
for module 'lodash/_initCloneObject'. 

'/Users/.../app/node_modules/lodash/_initCloneObject.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

  If the 'lodash' package actually exposes this module,
  consider sending a pull request to amend  
  'https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/lodash'

83 import initCloneObject from 'lodash/_initCloneObject';                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Have you tried adding [typeRoots](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) for your types in `tsconfig.json` or adding `src/types/lodash.d.ts` in the `include` array for `tsconfig.json`?